# How to get a corresponding column while selecting max value?

Tags: sql, group-by, max, common-table-expression

I have a rather complicated query but for the sake of completeness I will post it as it is:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        t.ID, t.TYPE, t.DATE, COUNT(*) AS count_30_days
    FROM 
        ASQ_AFTERSALES.TYPE AS t
    INNER JOIN 
        ASQ_AFTERSALES.TYPE i ON t.DATE >= ADD_DAYS (i.DATE, -30)
                              AND t.DATE <= i.DATE
                              AND t.TYPE = i.TYPE
    GROUP BY 
        t.ID, t.TYPE, t.DATE
)
SELECT 
    TYPE, MAX(count_30_days) AS max_incidence
FROM 
    cte
GROUP BY 
    TYPE
```

What is happening here is that I am applying a rolling window to the Date column and I am counting the occurrence in the last 30 days.
From these values I want to have the maximum for each type.

That's what the surrounding statement is for (which is the interesting one).

Of course I have multiple rows before calculating the max value but I want to get the max value of the column count_30_days but also get the corresponding date.

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        t.ID, t.TYPE, t.DATE, COUNT(*) AS count_30_days
    FROM 
        ASQ_AFTERSALES.TYPE AS t
    INNER JOIN 
        ASQ_AFTERSALES.TYPE i ON t.DATE >= ADD_DAYS (i.DATE, -30)
                              AND t.DATE <= i.DATE
                              AND t.TYPE = i.TYPE
    GROUP BY 
        t.ID, t.TYPE, t.DATE
)
SELECT 
    TYPE, MAX(count_30_days) AS max_incidence, DATE
FROM 
    cte
GROUP BY 
    TYPE, DATE
```

Running this query, I get the following error:

> Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

And it makes sense. How do I get the corresponding `DATE` to the `MAX(count_30_days)` row?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this. You want to show an additional column for wich the aggregated value is the MAX. That can be done in multiple ways, but the easiest is to use the `KEEP` keyword. Here is a simpler example. There is a table with a TYPE column and a DATE column. I want to show the date for the highest type count.

```
create table sample (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint sample_id_pk primary key,
    type                           varchar2(30 char),
    dt                             date
)
;

-- load data
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'A',  DATE'2023-07-01' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'A',  DATE'2023-07-01' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'A',  DATE'2023-07-01' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'A',  DATE'2023-07-02' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'A',  DATE'2023-07-04' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'A',  DATE'2023-07-02' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'A',  DATE'2023-07-05' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'B',  DATE'2023-07-04' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'B',  DATE'2023-07-04' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'B',  DATE'2023-07-05' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'B',  DATE'2023-07-02' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'B',  DATE'2023-07-02' );
insert into sample ( type, dt ) values ( 'B',  DATE'2023-07-03' );

WITH cte AS 
(
select type, dt, count(*) as cnt from sample group by type, dt
)
select type, max(cnt) as cnt, max(dt) keep (dense_rank first order by cnt desc) as dt
from cte
group by type;

TYPE                           CNT        DT
------------------------------ ---------- -----------
A                                       3 01-JUL-2023
B                                       2 04-JUL-2023
```

It shouldn't be too hard to apply this example to your dataset.

This is very well explained (along with the other possibilities to solve this issue) in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlTI_ZUyE0U) by @Connor McDonald

Comment: That is incredibly useful. Is there a bracket missing behind dense_rank? I get a syntax error near keep.

Comment: Good catch.  the column alias (as dt) needed to be after the (dense_rank...) statement - it was in front of it. Updated the post it should work ok now.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I now get a syntax error near "(". If it helps a I am quering a sap hana db. Maybe I need to use a different keyword than "dense_rank"?

Comment: hmm... apologies. I assumed this was an oracle db and my solution works on an oracle db (I tested it there). I'm not familiar with sap hana. I'd tag my question with the correct db - there are flavours of sql around. What works on one db doesn't necessarily work another.

Comment: Yes, it's my fault for not specifying the flavor. Do you maybe have an idea which function exactly may be the problem? Thanks anyways for the help!

Comment: No, but I suggest you want the video I have linked. Connor shows different ways in which this problem can be tackled, probably the other ones can be ported to sap hana

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    t.ID, 
    t.TYPE, 
    t.DATE, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.TYPE, t.DATE) AS count_30_days
FROM ASQ_AFTERSALES.TYPE AS t
INNER JOIN ASQ_AFTERSALES.TYPE i
    ON t.DATE >= ADD_DAYS(i.DATE, -30)
    AND t.DATE <= i.DATE
    AND t.TYPE = i.TYPE
),

ranked AS (
SELECT 
    TYPE, 
    count_30_days, 
    DATE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TYPE ORDER BY count_30_days DESC) as rn
FROM cte

)
SELECT 
TYPE, 
count_30_days AS max_incidence, 
DATE
FROM ranked
WHERE rn = 1
```

What I am doing is calculating the count for every type in the last 30 days. After that we make a new cte called ranked which numbers all counts (using ROW_NUMBER()) ordered by the quantity. The result is that for every type the highest quantity gets the row number 1. With that you can just select the results which have row number = 1 and you get only the MAX value.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very interesting. Unfortunately I run out of memory for my large dataset. Is this very memory expensive? I will try to figure it out.

Comment: I mean not really. Or at least I would not see why. How much memory do you have installed and how big is your SQL DB?